# Is it possible to develop a Blu-ray player for the Xbox One?

Tags: uwp, media-player, windows-10-universal, xbox

I've read that "The first UWP for the Xbox One is the new Blue-ray player app"

This makes me think ... is this app using an internal MS API or could a simple programmer develop a custom Blue-ray/DVD player?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a internal API, because such functionality is not yet available even on desktop UWP (you can't easily access disk mechanic). Maybe you could access the files on the drive via `FolderPicker` or `FileOpenPicker`, but I am afraid it will not work as the file explorer is will not list the drive there.

Comment: It was too useful to be true. It seems to be really difficult to build a custom player for DRM protected content (in any of it's forms) without being, at least, a medium sized company

Comment: @SantiagoRuiz If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

No. The XBOX One's UWP 
API surface does not include access to the disc drive, for obvious reasons (tampering with game data, etc), nor does the XBOX One 'File Picker' provide a view into the Disc Drive contents.

You can view which APIs are available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/uwp-limitations-on-xbox